# Creating an interactive legend with d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I've been following the codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/neilzo/pen/yNwrbq) and am hung up on the part in the legend where you can click a legend block to hide/show those points.

```
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", function(year) {
    var yearClass = '.y' + year;

    if (d3.selectAll(yearClass).classed('hide')) {
      d3.selectAll(yearClass).classed('hide', false);
    } else {
      d3.selectAll("circle:not(" + yearClass + ")")
        .classed("hide", function(d, i) {
          return !d3.select(this).classed("hide");
        });
    }
  });
```

I've changed my code to this:

```
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", function(state) {
console.log(state)
    if (d3.selectAll(state).classed('hide')) {
      d3.selectAll(state).classed('hide', false);
    } else {
      d3.selectAll("circle:not(" + state + ")")
        .classed("hide", function(d, i) {
          console.log(d)
          return !d3.select(this).classed("hide");
        });
    }
  });
```

And I keep getting an error message

> d3.js:685 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

State shows up but there is something wrong with the "else" part of the code.

A snippet of the code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}

div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;     
    text-align: center;     
  
    padding: 2px;       
    font: 12px sans-serif;    
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;    
    border-radius: 8px;     
    pointer-events: none;     
}
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 80},
    width = 1500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")       
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data/fiveMilesRadius.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Total_Pop = +d.Total_Pop;
    d.Med_HHD_Inc = +d.Med_HHD_Inc;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Med_HHD_Inc; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Total_Pop; })).nice();

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Median Household Income");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Total Population")

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d.State;
  })
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Med_HHD_Inc); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Total_Pop); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.State); })
              .on("mouseover", function(d) {    
            div.transition()    
                .duration(200)    
                .style("opacity", .9);    
            div .html(d.City + ", " + d.State)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")   
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");  
            })          
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {   
            div.transition()    
                .duration(500)    
                .style("opacity", 0); 
        });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", function(state) {
console.log(state)
    if (d3.selectAll(state).classed('hide')) {
      d3.selectAll(state).classed('hide', false);
    } else {
      d3.selectAll("circle:not(" + state + ")")
        .classed("hide", function(d, i) {
          console.log(d)
          return !d3.select(this).classed("hide");
        });
    }
  });


  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```